# Prevent a particular hierarchy of types being used for a generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I started this question with a load of background of the types in question; the interfaces and rationale behind the architecture.

Then I realised - 'This is SO - keep it simple and get to the point'.

So here goes.

I have a class like this:

```
public class AGenericType<T> : AGenericTypeBase
{
  T Value { get; set; }
}
```

.Net then, of course, allows me to do this:

```
AGenericType<AGenericType<int>> v;
```

However, in the context of `AGenericType<T>`'s usage, it is a nonsense to do this in the same way that it's a nonsense to do this:

```
Nullable<Nullable<double>> v;
```

What I want to be able to do is restrict this generic type so that it becomes impossible to create such an instance or even declare a reference to the type when it's `T` is derived from `AGenericTypeBase` - preferably at compile-time.

Now an interesting thing here is that the `Nullable<T>` example I give here *does indeed* generate a compiler error.  But I can't see how `Nullable<T>` restricts the `T` to non-`Nullable<T>` types - since `Nullable<T>` is a struct, and the only generic constraint I can find (even in the IL, which often yields compiler secrets, like those with delegates) is `where T:struct`.  So I'm thinking that one must be a compiler hack (*EDIT: See @Daniel Hilgarth's answer + comments below for a bit of an exploration of this*).  A compiler hack I can't repeat of course!

For my own scenario, IL and C# *don't* allow a negative-assert constraint like this:

```
public class AGenericType<T> : where !T:AGenericTypeBase
```

(note the '!' in the constraint)

But what alternative can I use?

I've thought of two:

1) Runtime exception generated in the constructor of an `AGenericType<T>`:

```
public AGenericType(){
  if(typeof(AGenericBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

That doesn't really reflect the nature of the error, though - because the problem is the generic parameter and therefore the whole type; not just that instance.

2) So, instead, the same runtime exception, but generated in a static initializer for `AGenericType<T>`:

```
static AGenericType(){
  if(typeof(AGenericBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

But then I'm faced with the problem that this exception will be wrapped inside a `TypeInitializationException` and could potentially cause confusion (in my experience developers that actually read a whole exception hierarchy are thin on the ground).

To me, this is a clear case for 'negative assertion' generic constraints in IL and C# - but since that's unlikely to happen, what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I have gone with an exception in the static initialiser of the generic type as it demonstrates more clearly that there is something wrong with the caller's *use of the type* as opposed to a runtime argument passed to a constructor.  The error is easily fixed by the caller, so I think its the best compromise.

Comment: I am accepting my own answer because neither of the others actually provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

About `Nullable<T>`: The constraint `T : struct` is the reason for the compiler error, because a variable of a struct can never be null, whereas a variable of type `Nullable<T>` can be null.
So, it **is** a compiler hack but only in that way, that `Nullable<T>` is treated like a nullable value type instead of a non-nullable value type.

```
public struct Nullable2<T> where T: struct
{
}

// Both lines will generate the same error
Nullable2<Nullable<int>> v;
Nullable<Nullable<int>> v2;
```

What I want to say is the following:
`Nullable<T>` doesn't do a "'negative assertion' generic constraints".

Comment: Yes I see - the compiler has a special knowledge (i.e. is hacked to know) that Nullable<T> is, unlike any other struct, *nullable*. I wonder if this 'special' knowledge is applied at the Code->IL level or at the IL interpreter level.  Time to try and generate some IL that declares a Nullable<Nullable<double>>

Comment: @Andras: I guess, this can easily be found out by writing IL code that does `Nullable<Nullable<int>>` and see whether it compiles.

Comment: @Daniel - yeah - looks like you responded before I edited that bit into the comment :)

Comment: @Daniel - well, one thing's for sure, you can't do `typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Nullable<double>))`; so I'm guessing both a .Net framework check (for runtime reflection) and at compiler level too.  Could probably cook the type handles manually though; just not entirely sure how at the moment; and not sure I can be bothered!

Comment: @Andras: What happens? But I guess, this was to be expected, because this will check the constraint and see that `Nullable<double>` is nullable and therefore doesn't conform to the constraint.

Comment: @Daniel - "GenericArguments[0], 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]', on 'System.Nullable`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'." is the error.

I think the phrase in the US would be: `DENIED!`

Comment: @Daniel - also with reference to your final paragraph - I wasn't saying that Nullable<T> *does* do a negative assert; but agree that the wording of my following paragraph ('IL and C# *don't* allow a negative-assert constraint like this') implied that I was saying that. I have reworded slightly.  The nature of this Nullable<T> and .Net framework 'special relationship' is interesting, however.

Comment: @Daniel, @Andras: The `Nullable<T>`/`struct` constraint behaviour is indeed enforced at the CLI level, so I'd be surprised if you manage to workaround it successfully. Section 10.1.7 of the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) says: "`valuetype` is a special-purpose constraint that constrains *Id* to being a value type, except that that type shall not be `System.Nullable<T>` or any concrete closed type of `System.Nullable<T>`." (The `valuetype` constraint is the CLI name for the `struct` constraint in C#.)

Comment: @LukeH - okay; yes; I guess by sticking it in the CLI spec makes it not a hack.

Doesn't help any of us that want to create our own generic that will have a similar behaviour, but which excludes a given base or interface!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I clearly understood your problem, and I believe you need a marker interface.

How can you ensure that some generic paremeter `T` doesn't inherit from some class? Well, since you can't do that, you can create a marker interface called "IWhatever" (change 'Whatever' with your own name that fits your needs) and use it to differentiate kinds of A:

```
public class B<T> 
   where T : A, IWhatever
```

**T inherits A, but A must implement IWhatever.**

You'd implement as many marker interfaces as you need in order to have different `T` kinds.

**Update:**

Has this something to do with *how to constraint T mustn't inherit A*?

Absolutely. If I need that, I use marker interfaces: `IIsNotA` and you can have this constraint: `T : IIsNotA`.

It's just an example. In a real-world scenario, `IIsNotA` would be called with a proper identifier related to some class hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure how this helps me say *T can inherit anything *except* A*

Comment: No problem. Well, it's giving you an idea: marker interfaces. Let me update the answer so I can explain it better.

Comment: Yup totally understand - but the only way I can make that pattern work is to add that interface to `int`, `double`, `string` etc etc - i.e. types that are not under my control

Comment: Anyway, this solution will be useful in custom hierarchies as you said, but you know you've `class` constraint, so `T` will be restricted to be a class instead of a struct. You've many options - I know that this doesn't solve all cases, because you've the case of a compiled class hierarchy without source code -...

Comment: @Matías - absolutely; I totally agree with you that this solution does help when you need to restrict generics to certain known hierarchies.